# android how to show a fragment taking a list of object

Tags: android, fragment

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
            b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.i("hi","onClick()");
                    Fragment f = ProductListFragment.newInstance(productArray);
                    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    ft.replace(R.id.fragment, f);
                    ft.commit();
                }
            });
```

This is in the main activity letting user click the button to create a fragment containing the productArray data.

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.GridView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ProductListFragment extends Fragment{

    private ArrayList<Product> productArray;

    public ArrayList<Product> getProductArray() {
        return productArray;
    }

    public void setProductArray(ArrayList<Product> productArray) {
        this.productArray = productArray;
    }

    public static Fragment newInstance(ArrayList<Product> productArray){

        ProductListFragment productListFragment = new ProductListFragment();
        productListFragment.setProductArray(productArray);

        return productListFragment;
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        GridView gridView = (GridView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_list_fragment, container, false);
        gridView.setNumColumns(2);
        gridView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        gridView.setAdapter(  new CustomGridAdapter( getActivity(), getProductArray() ) );
        return gridView;
    }
}
```

This is the fragment class putting data in productArray into a grid view which is fine in previous tests.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:padding="10dp">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="open fragment"
        android:id="@+id/button"/>

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="com.it.fyp.fyprestaurant.ProductListFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragment"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

This is the activity_main.xml. I knew that if I make fragment in this way, an error will occur because the productArray is null. Is a fragment tag needed, for reserving the place for the fragment or whatever reasons? How can I show the new fragment? pls help!

Answer (score 0):

You should add productArray to bundle and get the productArray from the bundle and `Product` model needs to implement Parcelable.

```
private static final String BUNDLE_PRODUCT_LIST = "bundle_product_list";    

public static Fragment newInstance(ArrayList<Product> productArray){

    ProductListFragment productListFragment = new ProductListFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelableArrayList(BUNDLE_PRODUCT_LIST, productArray);
    productListFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return productListFragment;
} 

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    if (getArguments() != null) {
       productArray = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList(BUNDLE_PRODUCT_LIST);
    }
}
```

========================================

UPDATED:

Parcelable example:

```
public class Product implements Parcelable {
    private String id;
    private String name;

    public Product(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Product> CREATOR
            = new Parcelable.Creator<Product>() {
        public Product createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Product(in);
        }

        public Product[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Product[size];
        }
    };

    private Product(Parcel in) {
        id = in.readString();
        name = in.readString();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int i) {
        // Make sure the order of writeString must be the same order 
        // as in.readString of the constructor above. 
        out.writeString(id);
        out.writeString(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: how to make ArrayList<Product> to be parceable[]

Comment: Sorry I just updated to `putParcelableArrayList` so that you can pass ArrayList<Product>

Comment: implementing Parcelable need  implement the abstract method?

Comment: Yes, you can refer to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html. how to implement those methods.

Comment: in those two abstract , what should i do ? nothing?

Comment: " java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView" occurs when the button is clicked

Comment: That looks like a different issue, you might want to consider opening a new question, if the problem persists.